# How to insert more than one value into one column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert more than one value in columns `SellPrice1`, `SellPrice2`.

Because maybe one of my items has 2 or 3 sell prices.

[image]

Comment: This is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: For reasons of normalization it is best to create a new entry for each item that has multiple sell prices. If you are storing multiple things in one field it is usually bad practice.

Comment: Repeating columns like this is an anti-pattern caused by by normalization. It violates the rule of 1NF that you not have repeating attributes. Don't do this to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either add an [ItemSalePrice3] column, but that could go on for ever, and you usually don't want your DB to grow horizontally instead of vertically.

I would personally add a table like:

```
item_id    price
_________________
1          1,50
1          2,00
2          4,00
```

And add an entry to that table for each price an item has.

Comment: that mean i have to delete Fields (SellPrice1,SellPirce2) of Items Table